# How can I create a separate dynamic window in my React app?

Tags: reactjs, twilio, react-portal

My React app incorporates a video chat function (via Twilio).  The user goes to a dashboard and then clicks a button to start the call. This prompts the `VideoCall` component to be instantiated and shown.  On instantiation, it connects to a backend Twilio service to get an access token, and then connects to Twilio to create the call, set up events handlers etc.

Currently I'm showing the video windows in a div within the dashboard, but I would like them to appear in a pop-out window instead.  I've tried using react-new-window and I've tried React Portals, but I didn't know enough about what I was doing to make it work.

Currently I have the following `Dashboard` component:

```
function Dashboard(props) {

  const { displayInfo} = props
  const [ callInitiated, setCallInitiated ] = useState(false)

  const initCall = () => {
    setCallInitiated(true)
  }

  return (
    <div id="dashboard">
      {callInitiated ? <VideoCall displayInfo={displayInfo} /> : null }
      <div> ...rest of dashboard, including button which calls 'initCall' on being clicked... </div>
    </div>
  )

}

export default Dashboard
```

My `VideoCall` component is:

```
const Video = require('twilio-video');

// Get access token from backend service
async function getAccessToken(identity) {

    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_TWILIO_TOKEN_SERVICE}?identity=${identity}`;
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${url}`, AXIOS_HEADERS);
        return response.data.accessToken;
    } catch {
        return null;
    }

}

// VideoCall component
function VideoCall(props) {

    const { displayInfo} = props

    // Connect to Twilio server function to get access token
    getAccessToken('Tester')
    .then((token) => {
      Video.connect(token, {
        name: 'Test room'
      })
      .then(room => {
        participantConnected(room.localParticipant);
        room.participants.forEach(participantConnected);
        room.on('participantConnected', participantConnected);
        room.on('participantDisconnected', participantDisconnected);
        room.once('disconnected', error => room.participants.forEach(participantDisconnected))
      })
    });

    function participantConnected(participant) {
    
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.id = participant.sid;
    
      participant.on('trackSubscribed', track => trackSubscribed(div, track));
      participant.on('trackUnsubscribed', trackUnsubscribed);
    
      participant.tracks.forEach(publication => {
          trackSubscribed(div, publication.track);
      });

      if(participant.identity === 'Tester') {
        document.getElementById('myVideoWindow').appendChild(div)
      }
      
    }
    
    function participantDisconnected(participant) {
      document.getElementById(participant.sid).remove();
    }
    
    function trackSubscribed(div, track) {
      div.appendChild(track.attach());
    }
    
    function trackUnsubscribed(track) {
      track.detach().forEach(element => element.remove());
    }

    return (
          <div id="callWrapper" className="callOuterWrapper">
              <div className="titleBar">
                  <h1 className="pageHeader">Calling {displayInfo.receiverName}</h1>
              </div>
              <div className="videoRoom">
                    <div id="myVideoWindow" className="callWindow"></div>
                    <div className="callInfo"> ...this will contain info on call status... </div>
                    <div id="receiverWindow" className="callWindow"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
    )
}

export default VideoCall
```

So far, this works.  The user clicks the button and the video windows appear at the top of the dashbaord, as expected.

Now I want to pull the `VideoCall` component out into a separate window (so that the user can still see the dashboard while on the call.

I tried the package react-new-window, which just involved wrapping the `VideoCall` in a `NewWindow`.  I tried wrapping it within the `Dashboard` component:

```
<div id="dashboard">
  {callInitiated ? <NewWindow><VideoCall displayInfo={displayInfo} /></NewWindow> : null }
  <div> ...rest of dashboard, including button which calls 'initCall' on being clicked... </div>
</div>
```

and when that didn't work I tried wrapping within the `VideoCall` component:

```
<NewWindow>
   <div id="callWrapper" className="callOuterWrapper">...</div>
</NewWindow>
```

In both cases this displayed the new window with the empty `callWrapper` div; however, once it reached `document.getElementById('myVideoWindow').appendChild(div)` it was unable to find the div.  The DOM being referenced appears to be the one from the Dashboard window rather than the new windows (also, any `console.log` commands get logged to the console of the original window, not the new one).

I then tried taking apart the NewWindow code and creating my own bespoke version, but I don't know enough about how it works to make it do what I needed.

So, is there a way to access the DOM of the new window from the component within it?  Or is there a different approach I should be taking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Directly accessing the DOM with native DOM methods, like `document.getElementById`, is a little frowned upon within React. React itself should be in charge of adding and removing things from the DOM.

I wrote a post on [how to build a video chat with React](https://www.twilio.com/blog/video-chat-react-hooks) that covers how to add your participants to the page without accessing the DOM directly.

I'd recommend a look through that and perhaps updating your app so that you don't have to use `document.getElementById` and then hopefully the `<NewWindow>` component should work as advertised.

Comment: Thank you; I'll try that tomorrow!

Comment: Let me know how it goes!

Comment: I changed how this worked in the end, so that the video is in the same window as the rest.